# Under what conditions are trigonometric integrals over a period zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Often times, while solving a physics problem, for example, an integral involving only sines and cosines (and constants), over a period, must be solved. In many cases this may prove difficult, so it's useful to know when we can just cross it out. Under what conditions can we assume such an integral to be zero, and most importantly, why? What theorems and properties can we make use of?

Comment: Check if the function being integrated is odd. Other than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that should be considered is probably the symmetry of the integral. If the integral has lower and upper limits of equal magnitude (e.g. x = -5 to x = 5) and the function you are integrating is *even* then you can simply find the integral from x = 0 to x = 5 and double the answer. Even better, if the function is *odd*, you can indeed cross it out just like you hoped for, because the regions will have opposite signs on either side of the y-axis, yet be equal in size. These types of integrals are the best! So, maybe study up on how to determine if a function is odd or even if you are using a combination of odd and even functions, such as cosine and sine.

Comment: I see. It is indeed very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelNadal In case of trigonometric functions I believe you should pay attention also on the period of the function. For the sine it doesn't matter because it's odd and you can choose whatever interval where the upper and lower limits have an equal magnitude and the sum of the area will just cancel out. However for the cosine you should pick up an interval $[-T,T]$ where $T$ is equal or an integer multiple of the period (half of a period is also working). I remember this distinction when I dealt with problem like this. I don't know if this is a general rule.